# Design pattern for mouse interaction

Tags: qt, design-patterns

I need some opinions on what is the  "ideal" design pattern for a general mouse 
interaction.

Here the simplified problem. I have a small 3d program (QT and openGL) and 
I use the mouse for interaction. Every interaction is normally not only a
single function call, it is mostly performed by up to 3 function calls (initiate, perform, finalize).
For example, camera rotation:  here the initial function call will deliver the current first mouse position,
whereas the performing function calls will update  the camera etc.

However, for only a couple of interactions, hardcoding these (inside MousePressEvent, MouseReleaseEvent MouseMoveEvent or MouseWheelEvent etc)
is not a big deal, but if I think about a more advanced program (e.g 20 or more interactions) then a proper design is needed.

Therefore, how would you design such a interactions inside QT.

I hope I made my problem clear enough, otherwise don't bother complain :-)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest using polymorphism and the factory method pattern. Here's an example:

In my Qt program I have QGraphicsScenes and QGraphicsItems with mousePressEvent, mouseMoveEvent, and mouseReleaseEvent, which look like this:

```
void CustomItem::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
  // call factory method, which returns a subclass depending on where click occurred
  dragHandler = DragHandler::createDragHandler(event /* and other relevant stuff */);
}

void CustomItem::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
  dragHandler->onMouseMove(event);
}

void CustomItem::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
  dragHandler->onMouseRelease(event);
  delete dragHandler;
}
```

The idea in this particular case is that depending on where I click on CustomItem, mouse pressing, moving, and releasing will have different functionality. For example, if I click on the edge of the item, dragging will resize it, but if I click in the middle of the item, dragging will move it. DragHandler::onMouseMove and DragHandler::onMouseRelease are virtual functions that are reimplemented by subclasses to provide the specific functionality I want depending on where the mouse press occurred. There's no need for DragHandler::onMousePress because that's basically the constructor.

This is of course a rather specific example, and probably not exactly what you want, but it gives you an idea of how you can use polymorphism to clean up your mouse handling.

Comment: Thanks Anthony for your detailed answer. I will try to implement the factory  method, combined with the signal/slot mechanism.  Otherwise, I can't see how I can connect the openGL picking, which only gives me some ids, with the actual objects.

Answer (score 1):

Qt makes this beautifully simple.

Instead of all the `switch mouse_mode:` stuff you used to write, simply have each mouse event  handler function emit a signal ie. mouseDown/mouseUp/mousePosition and use signals/slots to route those to the appropriate model functions.

Then you can accommodate different uses of the mouse (selecting, rotating, editing etc) by connect/disconnect different SLOTS to the signal sent in the Mouse...Event()

Comment: Martin, thanks for the reply. In conjunction with the factory pattern the signal/slot  are possible a neat solution.

Answer (score 1):

I find Apple's [UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) design quite nice and extendable.

The idea is to decouple the recognition of the gesture (or interaction) and the action that will be triggered.

You need to implement a basic or abstract GestureRecognizer class that is able to recognize a certain interaction or gesture based on events MousePressEvent, MouseReleaseEvent MouseMoveEvent or MouseWheelEvent etc. GestureRecongnizers have a target to report changes periodically.

For example your very basic class would be like: (sorry my poor semi c++ pseudo-code ... recently I don't use it that much)

```
class Recognizer {
int state; // ex: 0:possible, 1:began, 2:changed, 3:ended/recognized 4:cancelled
protected:
void setTarget(void &theTarget); // or even better a touple, target/method. In this case target is assumed to have a method gestureHandle(Recognizer *r);
virtual void mouserPress() = 0;
virtual void mouserRelease() = 0;
virtual void mouserMove() = 0;
virtual void mouserWheel() = 0;
...
}
```

And if you want to detect a swipe with the mouse

```
class SwipeRecognizer : Recognizer {
int direction; // ex: 0:left2right 1:bottom2top 2:...
private:
void mouserPress() {
    state = 0; // possible. You don't know yet is the mouse is going to swipe, simple click, long press, etc.
    // save some values so you can calculate the direction of the swipe later 
    target.gestureHandle(this);
};
void mouserMove() {
    if (state == 0) {
        state = 1; // it was possible now you know the swipe began!
        direction = ... // calculate the swipe direction here
    } else if (state == 1 || state == 2) {// state is began or changed
        state = 2; // changed ... which means is still mouse dragging
        // probably you want to make more checks here like you are still swiping in the same direction you started, maybe velocity thresholds, if any of your conditions are not met you should cancel the gesture recognizer by setting its state to 4
    }
    target.gestureHandler(this);
};
void mouserRelease() {
    if (state == 2) { // is swipping
        state = 3; // swipe ended
    } else {
        state = 4; // it was not swiping so simple cancel the tracking
    }
    target.gestureHandler(this);
};
void mouserWheel() {
    // if this method is called then this is definitely not a swipe right?
    state = 4; // cancelled
    target.gestureHandler(this);
}
```

Just make sure above methods are called when the events are happening and they should call the target when needed.

This is how the target will look to me:

```
class Target {
...
void gestureHandler(Recognizer *r) {
    if (r->state == 2) {
        // Is swipping: move the opengl camera using some parameter your recognizer class brings
    } else if (r->state == 3) {
        // ended: stop moving the opengl camera
    } else if (r->state == 4) {
        // Cancelled, maybe restore camera to original position?
    }
}
```

Implementation of UIGestureRecognizer is quite nice and will allow to register several targets /method for the same recognizer and several recognizers to the same view.
UIGestureRecognizers have a delegate object that is used to get information about other gesture recognizers, for example, if two gestures can be detected at the same time, or should one must fail as soon as the other is detected, etc.

Some gesture recognizer will require more overrides than others but the big PRO of this is that their output is the same: a handler method that informs about the current state (and other info).

I think is worth taking a look at it

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hello nacho4d, thanks you very much for your detailed answer. At the moment the GestureRecognizer design seems to be a too general approach for my specific problem. Nevertheless, I will keep it into my mind, for later usage. thanks